# One dare not disobey?

Tags: verbs, inflectional-morphology, inflections, semi-modals

> When a mystery is too overpowering, one dare not disobey.

This is a sentence from [*The Little Prince* by Antoine de Saint-Exupéry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Prince). I am not sure why *dare* is in the infinitive, not the third person singular? Is it because that it is somewhat like *one* ***should*** *dare not disobey*?

Comment: I think it's because it's in the subjunctive case.

Comment: @TrevorD It's not in the subjunctive mood; rather, it's because _dare_ is here being used as a modal verb (which do not inflect according to person—or in some people's view, at all), rather than as a regular verb. That's mostly a historical difference: _dare_ used to be mostly modal, now it's mostly not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks. I knew the form "dare" was correct, but was only guessing why!

Comment: @Janus: So according to these people who don't believe modals inflect, *"one dare not disobey*" is modal, but *"one dared not disobey"* is no longer modal? I don't believe that. Doesn't *"one dared not disobey"* have to be modal, because otherwise you would need *do* support?  *"One dared not to disobey"* is clearly wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor Interesting question! Modal *dare* and *need* are today used mainly in negative and interrogative contexts: *she need never, he dare not.* For inflections, *dare* further has an old preterite inflection *durst* which although still sometimes found in regional speech is otherwise relegated to archaizing or rusticizing use; Gollum used it, for example. But even *durst* has no 3s inflection, being in the preterite where only *be* observes a singular–plural distinction (in the indicative).

Comment: @tchrist: modal *need* has always been used mainly in negative and interrogative context. It replaced the modal *[tharf](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tharf)*, which was also used mainly in negative and interrogative contexts. I don't know if this was also true for modal *dare*.

Comment: I should add that Samwise and Faramir also use *durst*. Sam: *“Mr. Frodo, he left the last pages of the Book to me, but I **have never yet durst to put** hand to them.”* That doesn’t seem to be modal there, in contrast with Faramir’s *“Then the boat turned towards me, and stayed its pace, and floated slowly by within my hand's reach, yet **I durst not handle** it.”* On rustic speech, between 1937 and 1951, Tolkien respelled one of Gollum’s uses of *durstn’t* to *dursn’t*, dropping an unspoken *-t-* that no one could ever say anyway: *“But **we dursn’t go** in, precious, no we dursn’t.”*

Comment: @tchrist: looking in the OED, almost all their citations for modal *dare* since the 16th century have been in negative, interrogative, or hypothetical contexts. It looks like it was used in positive contexts in Middle English, and more recently in Scotland (their citation – Robert Burns: *I daur you try sic sportin*).

Comment: They also have some citations from the 18th and 19th century where uninflected modal *dare* was used in the past tense as well. (It seems to have been trying to turn into a true modal verb, but it didn't succeed.)

Comment: @PeterShor According to those people, I suspect _dare_ and _dared_ would be considered two different modal verbs. I don't agree with those people, I might add.